# Webpage layout structure

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to get my basic webpage layout together and I hit a few problems. Could someone please help me solve it. My understanding of CSS is not superb.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/HJLzt/

1. The sticky footer is working, and I want to have a column left and right of the page in between header and footer. I'm not sure if the way I did it is correct.
2. Between left and right column and header and footer I would like to put the content. How do I center it. I cannot find a proper way, as there is always overflow and I want it only to go between the left and right column and nothing to cut off.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:
I have updated my layout and used a bit of jquery to help out. I know I should try and make everything work in css, but it seems impossible.

Maybe I should add, that I want a whiteboard as theme. I want a wooden frame, so the sidebars always have to connect to the header and footer, as the top and bottom frames go through there.

If somebody could have a look and tell me if that is ok or not.

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

#main { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#main header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5d3be6;
}

footer{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #afeba4; 
}


/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */

#layout_left{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f21ce7;
}

#layout_right{

    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    background-color: #f21ce7;
}

#content_layout{
    border-left: 100px solid #e4f662;
    border-right: 100px solid #e4f662;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #c36161;
}

#content{
    margin: auto;
    width: 96%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated you're new to CSS but I'd very much recommend against your layout, it's seemingly 10 years ago standard. (no offense intended ofcourse, you're new to this, you're not going to know the do's and do not's as of yet).

Research online portfolio examples using google for ideas!

to answer your question:

I recognise your sticky footer code, I didn't work for me either, well not completely.

It doesn't work great, I'd recommend:  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

I'd tell you myself but that tutorial is very well written and easy to understand and implement.

And for centering container use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

centering text you can use:

```
text-align: center;
```

Hope that helps.